# How static object gets initialized at compile time?

Tags: c++

```
class Bird {
public:
   Bird() {
     .....
     .....
    }    
};

void fun() {
    static Bird obj;
}
```

When compiler compiles the statement **static Bird obj** It does 2 thing. First is memory allocation for object obj. Second is initialization of obj by calling constructor. My question is if initialization part happens in compile time, how all the statement inside constructor will be executed at compile time

Answer (score 3):

At compile time, the compiler will set aside a chunk of memory in a special static object area which is part of the program space. That memory will be uninitialized.

Inside the function, the compiler will put an invisible "if" statement which detects that the static object statement is being executed for the first time. If it is the first time, the constructor for the object will be called.

Answer (score 2):

> When compiler compiles the statement static Bird obj It does 2 thing.
>   First is memory allocation for object obj. Second is initialization of
>   obj by calling constructor.

No. The memory is already allocated at compile time (before the program gets executed). It's just that initialization happens when the execution touches the `static Bird obj;` statement. This is called **lazy initialization**.

Also, note that, in case if `Bird()` constructor throws an exception, then the initialization will not be finished. So again when the `fun()` is called, `obj` is again tries to get initialized. It happens until the `obj` initializes successfully. After that, that line will not be executed any more.

Answer (score 1):

static initialization does not happen at compile time. It happens at run-time, but before main() is invoked.

The order in which static initialization spread across compilation units is not defined. Hence, if you really need static variables, the recommended way is to put all of them on a single static_constructors.cpp, and as a extra benefit, they'll be easier to find

Comment: `It happens at run-time, but before main() is invoked.` Is this correct ?

Comment: @iammilind: the OP is referring to a static variable at function scope, though, so you do know when it's getting initialized, namely at the first invocation of the function.

Comment: @Kerrek, so how static initialization of `obj` can happen before `main()`. Allocation happens before `main()` not the initialization.

Comment: Except that here, the static variable has local scope.  It will be initialized the first time the normal program flow encounters the statement (maybe never).

Comment: *Allocation* happens at load-time, indeed, both for functions-scope statics and for global statics. Initialization for functions-scope statics happens at first invocation, but initalization for global statics happens before `main()`, in no specified order.

Answer (score 0):

In that situation, `static` has a different meaning. It means that `obj` will be initialized only once, at the first time `fun()` is called and `obj` will remaing valid between calls to `fun()`.

Think of it as a global variable, but only the function `fun()` can see it :P